# Why wont this code show the hunger variable?

Tags: javascript, html

Does anyone know how to make it so every ten seconds hunger goes down by one. the biggest problem im
having is that it wont show hunger at all.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta http-equiv="CONTENT-TYPE" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css" />
  <title>fun</title>
</head>

<body>
  <script>
    var health = 5;
    var hunger = 10;

    function task(i) {
      setTimeout(() {
        hunger -= 1;
      }, 1000 * i);
      document.write("<b>" + hunger + "</b>");
      document.getElementById('hunger-div').innerHTML = hunger;
    }


    for (let i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
      task(i);
    }
  </script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: If you want to change the DOM inside the timeout callback, you have to *put the code that changes the DOM* inside the timeout callback

Comment: You have syntax errors in your Javascript. `setTimeout(() {` must be  `setTimeout(()=>{` Check the console of your browser's developer tools (F12 on Windows). Also when you use `document.write` after the stream has closed (like you do) that replaces your whole document. Next you don't have an element with `id="hunger-div"`.

Comment: also, I don't know if that's the complete code snippet but you don't have an element with the id `hunger-div`, therefore your changes to this "element" will not do anything other than causing an error.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You need to have a `div` with the `id` attribute set to a unique value. This allows you to modify the contents of said `div`. Also, you don't need to both call `document.write` and set `innerHTML`.

The code below utilizes the `setTimeout` function, to which you pass a function and a timeout (in milliseconds), with the function being run after the timeout elapses.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
    <title>Hunger!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hunger-div"><b>10</b></div>
    <script>
        let hunger = 10;

        function task(seconds) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                hunger -= 1;
                document.getElementById('hunger-div').innerHTML = `<b>${hunger}</b>`;
            } , 10 * 1000 * seconds);
        }   
    
        for (let seconds = 1; seconds<=10; i++) {
            task(seconds);
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

You can also use `setInterval`, which takes a function and a delay and runs the function every time the delay has elapsed.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles/style.css"/>
    <title>Hunger!</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="hunger-div"><b>10</b></div>
    <script>
        let hunger = 10;

        let intervalID = setInterval(() => {
           hunger -= 1;
           document.getElementById('hunger-div').innerHTML = `<b>${hunger}</b>`;

           if (hunger === 0) {
               clearInterval(intervalID);
           }
        }, 10 * 1000);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: The OP said that their biggest problem is showing the hunger variable. Although your code shows it, it doesn't update it as it decreases. Your answer also doesn't give very much detail about **why** it works. One sentence about what you need doesn't really explain why it works. Not necessarily a **wrong** answer, just not a high quality answer. However, it's also hard to get high quality answers when the question has -7 votes.

Comment: ok thats exactly what i want sorry for the confusion

Comment: i would but i just created an account for this website so it says it wont be displayed

Comment: @AshtonSheranian thanks, hope the answer helped!